# How many iterations are generally required when using the power iteration method?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, markov-chains

Suppose I have an *n* x *n* matrix and I want to find the dominant eigenvalue and its associated eigenvector.  Given these dimensions, what is the minimum number of iterations of the power iteration method that I should use to cause the values to converge in such a fashion that the ranks of the matrix will be accurate?  (I.e., I want every element of the eigenvector to be < or > other elements of the eigenvector correctly.)

Comment: In the power method, you have to determine the eigenvector as the vector to which $A^k x_0$ converges upto a scalar multiple. Mention in question how you are going to determine this converging eigenvector from $Ax_0,A^2x_0,A^3x_0,....A^kx_0$ i.e., from this sequence, what is your proposed eigenvector mathematically ? Further tell us how are you going to choose the initial vector $x_0$ ?

Answer (score 1):

The elements in the leading eigenvector can be arbitrarily close to zero and I believe this means that in arbitrary powers of the matrix, you may get that the apparent leading eigenvector of the power matrix (i.e. the entries in the matrix raised to a power applied to an arbitrary non-zero vector) have entries out of order with respect to the order of the entries of the true leading eigenvector of the matrix.